# Where did I go wrong in this Euler Proof

Tags: solution-verification

Why are the two proofs below contradicting each other?

- $e^{iπ} = -1 $
- $e^{π2i}= (e^{iπ})^2 = 1$
- $(e^{π2i})^π = 1$

Part 2

- $(e^{π2i})^π = e^{{π^2}2i}$
- $cos(2{π^2}) = i sin(2{π^2})$  ≠ 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $z^{ab} = (z^{a})^b$ is not true for complex numbers